# Why do stdint.h can be found but cstdint not?

Tags: c++, g++, stdint, acc

I'm be suprised with that include stdint.h works but include cstdint not.

```
$ aCC sizeof.cpp
"sizeof.cpp", line 5: error #2005-D: could not open source file "cstdint"
  #include <cstdint>
                    ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "sizeof.cpp".
$ aCC --version
aCC: HP C/aC++ B3910B A.06.12 [Nov 03 2006]
```

It's same with g++:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.2.3
```

May I ask why? And, have any method to fixed this problem but updating compiler?
Thank you.

Comment: Where does `cstdint` come from?

Comment: In gcc 4.2.3, you might find `<cstdint>` under tr1 `<tr1/cstdint>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your compiler supports the old C++ standard which has no `<cstdint>` (as C90 had no `<stdint.h>`). `<cstdint>` is new to C++11.

Comment: @Charles Bailey is right. Latest gcc (4.6.3) on my machine has experimental support for C++0x and warns "#error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options."

Comment: Oh, i see, thank you. But now, the question is: why does c99 support stdint.h but c++03 dose not support cstdint?

Comment: @van: That's just the way it is. The version of the C standard referenced by C++03 (because it's only a minor update to C++98) is/was still C90.