# imwrite throwing compile error in OpenCV

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, compiler-errors

I have been using OpenCV for a while and also the `imwrite` function, but unfortunately this is not working any more.

I am running with OpenCV 2.4.3 with following sample code:

```
imwrite("somepath/somefile.png", myMat);
```

The error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"cv::imwrite(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::__debug::vector<int,     std::allocator<int> > const&)", referenced from:
MyProject::this_callback(int, void*) in MyProject.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The error looks somewhat familiar but i cannot determine whats wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I've thought you were using XCode. I had the same problem. :)

If you change the project setup so that:

- you use GNU++11 as C++ language dialect
- libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard) as C++ standard library

your linking problem will go away.

I use Apple LLVM 4.1.

---

When I had this problem, I have tried just adding a new target to one of my old projects I knew, worked. Then I've just made that target a one-source-file program.

This must be a "magic" part of XCode as I think there was a time I could not get the same project working after a restart. :S

Comment: I was actually hoping that you were right since my old project has some similiar settings for the compilers. I am running LLVM 3.1 a rather old version, but workable. Please seem my original post, with the screenshot. The error has still not been resolved.

Comment: I've just recently updated to XCode 4.5 and it works fine for me. I was worried because originally I reverted to XCode 4.2 as I had some problems with XCode 4.3. But I can say, after 2-3 weeks I have no problem with the new version.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Xcode 5 with LLVM 5.0 and the settings above. OpenCV complains about "'cstdint' file not found" in cvdef.h when using libstdc++.

Answer (score 0):

I did what Barnabas did and also got the issue on cvdef.h. I was getting desperate so and what I did was just changed the header file.

in /usr/local/cvdef.h line 205:

I changed

```
include <cstdint>
typedef std::uint32_t uint;
```

to:

```
include <tr1/cstdint>
typedef std::tr1::uint32_t uint;
```

based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408458/why-do-stdint-h-can-be-found-but-cstdint-not)

I think opencv devs should apply some changes to the code for 64bit..

Answer (score 0):

use something like `clang version 3.8.0 (trunk 257459)`, instead of `gcc version 4.9.2 (MacPorts gcc49 4.9.2_1+universal)` to compile

for reference, cmd: clang++ -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` code.cpp -o code